# how to keep data filled in form fields when go next page angular 2

Tags: html, angular

In angular 2 I have a form that when user complete it and click next page the data that filled will show in the next page. My html of both page are the same but the second has extra fields. I want the fields that are common in both pages get that data were in first page.
for example one of the fields is like this:

```
<div class="group col-md-4 form-group">
        <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.numOfBeds" name="beds" type="text" required #beds="ngModel">
        <span class="highlight"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label>Number Of Beds</label>
        <div [hidden]="beds.valid || beds.pristine"
             class="alert alert-danger">
          Please Fill!
        </div>
      </div>
```

please help me how to write code or give me some examples.
Thank you for your helping in simple way.

Comment: It seems like you want to make a service that holds all the formData

Comment: If you have the same data fields then why you are going to create new template. You can handle the extra fields in the same template also.

Comment: @jesusverma I mean in the first page I have some inputs that when user click on next page the page reload and show that inputs with data of inputs and show some extra inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your data in different routes using an Injectable class:

```
@Injectable
export class DataService {
  let data;

  setData(data) { this.data = data; }
  getData() { return this.data; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to save the data in to a local variable first and then return the data when you go to the next page :)